# Why is the API doc for GraspHandPostureExecution not generated?

Tags: ros, object-manipulation, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While editing the [katana](http://www.ros.org/wiki/katana) package wiki page, I would like to link to the GraspHandPostureExecution. However, the following code...

```
goal {
  0.name = posture_action_name/goal
  0.type = object_manipulation_msgs/GraspHandPostureExecutionActionGoal
  0.desc = Enables one to open or close the gripper via the GRASP or RELEASE command or to move the gripper to a arbitrary position choosing the PRE-GRASP option.
}
```

...produces the following link: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/object_manipulation_msgs/html/msg/GraspHandPostureExecutionActionGoal.html, which is dead. Somehow, the API documentation for this action seems not to be generated. For other actions, this pattern works, e.g. here: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/move_base_msgs/html/msg/MoveBaseActionGoal.html.

BTW, a copy of the page I would like to link to seems to be here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_manipulation_msgs/GraspHandPostureExecutionAction.

So, my questions are: why is the API doc not generated, and why is there a copy? And how do I make the Clearsilver macro link to the correct page?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9833/why-is-the-api-doc-for-grasphandpostureexecution-not-generated?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That action was in version 0.3 of object_manipulation, however it has been removed in version 0.4.  Currently the autogenerated docs are only for the latest released version.  We hope to be able to start generating multiple versions however that requires a significant overhaul of our documentation infrastructure which is why it hasn't happened quickly.  For stable stacks the documentation is usually fine.  However for unstable stacks you can see effects like this.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-10-24**:
Sorry to resuscitate this age-old question, but I just noticed that in version 0.5.4 of object_manipulation, the action is still there, and the API doc is still not generated.